# Custom Post form for Sharepoint 2016 Publishing Portal

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-form, publishing-site

I am working on a Public Facing web site(Publishing Portal) using Sharepoint 2016. My requirement is to create a custom form which looks like below.


[image]

My Question is.

1) How to create a Custom Form for Publishing Portal in Sharepoint which is able to post data.

2) Will I be able to post data to Sharepoint List as a site user? If so How to achieve it?

3) How can I protect that particular list so that nobody is able to read data from it using a rest api.


Looking forward to your replies please.

Answer (score 0):

Create farm solution with custom webpart(custom form you shared), [demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-farm-solution-using-visual-studio-2013-in-sharepoin/).

Use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` in your webpart to maintain list data.

http://mekishordas.blogspot.com/2013/03/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-sharepoint.html

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()  
    {  
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))  
        {  
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webID))  
            {  
                // Code Using the SPWeb Object goes here  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

Set list permission to owner only(break list permission), others can't read it.